# Fixed size for square div when using width % and padding-bottom %

Tags: html, css, square

I want to create a Flexbox with squares of fixed size.
Solved with width % and padding-bottom %.

But if I put a picture in there, it changes the size.

How do I solve this?

I tried max-width, max-padding-bottom (lol i know), padding-bottom: max(x%), ...

I don't have any idea now.

```css
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .flex-container > div {
    width: 32%;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0.5%;
 }

img.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      <img class="flex"     src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/KDE_4.png">
      
    </div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>  
</div>

<p> some text <p>
<p> some text <p>
  
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to use Stack Overflow snippets, is the result ok? (Click on "Run code snippet") Also, I didn't really understand your problem, can you try to explain a bit more in detail what you want the image to look like?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, the padding is also the room where you want the image to show.

- you can set image in absolute position.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container>div {
  width: 32%;
  padding-bottom: 32%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

img.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <img class="flex" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/KDE_4.png">

  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<p> some text
  <p>
    <p> some text
      <p>

        <div class="flex-container">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
```

- You could also use a pseudo element to stretch your div to a square to avoid to make it use the whole space.

  - it can be the parent

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container::before {
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: 33.33%;
  with: 0;
}

.flex-container>div {
  width: 32%;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)50%, transparent 50%) #000;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

img.flex {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;/*might be better ? */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <img class="flex" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/KDE_4.png">
  </div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<p> some text
  <p>
    <p> some text
      <p>
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div></div>
          <div>d</div>
          <div>d</div>
        </div>
```

- or the child

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container>div {
  width: 32%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.flex-container>div::before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
}

img.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <img class="flex" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/KDE_4.png">

  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<p> some text
  <p>
    <p> some text
      <p>

        <div class="flex-container">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
```

if  vertical padding or margin can be used to stretch a div using parent's width, you have also to mind the room used from the method.